# Как отследить события на чужом сайте с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые программисты javascript!
Меня мучает один вопрос - как отследить события на чужом сайте с помощью javascript? 
Буду благодарен, если поможете с ответом.
Вводные данные: есть чужой (то есть я не могу писать код на нем) одностраничный сайт с динамическим контентом.
Вопрос: можно ли, и если да, то каким образом, отследить изменение контента на этом сайте с помощью javascript?
Например, есть div'ы, в которых динамически появляется интересующая меня информация, и если в div'е обнаруживается мною заданное ключевое слово, то мне на рабочем столе выводится уведомление.
Сам функционал по выводу сообщения и обнаружению ключевого слова я сделаю. Мне лишь непонятно, как организовать отлов изменения контента на сайте. Ведь я не могу писать код на сайте.

Comment: пишите расширение для браузера. устанавливайте его и ждете

Comment: Вот как! :) Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всегда можно добавить клинетский код на страницу сайта при помощи расширения для браузера, но также можно просто вписать код в консоль браузера.
(Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)

В этом примере мы будем следить за изменениями в  `<div id="question-header">` прямо на этой странице.
Для этого скопируем этот код в консоль браузера.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('question-header');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    if (permission === "granted") {
      var notification = new Notification("Something has changed!");
    }
  });
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { 
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Затем, чтобы проверить, что всё работает давайте добавим элемент, прописав этот код опять же в консоль браузера.

```
var node = document.createElement("b");                
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hello new item");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("question-header").appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 2):

Данный код, получает содержимое div'a на текущем сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю обернуть его в цикл, и проверять содержимое, нужного вам блока html , по расписанию

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
 <div id='q'></div>

 <script>
  $('#q').load('https://crossorigin.me/http://ru.stackoverflow.com #nav-questions');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: этот способ не подойдет для динамических сайтов. Потому что загружать будет только статический контент.

Comment: @Grundy вы имеете ввиду, что если нужно кликнуть по кнопке для получение информации, то способ не подойдет?

Comment: да, это как самый простой пример

Answer (score 0):

ну, если задача сугубо разовая и сугубо для себя - то "какбы внедрить" js-код можно в консоли... если страничка обновляется динамически (т.е. без перезагрузки) - в консоли вешаете функцию на setInterval, и ждете...

если данные обновляются только путем полной перезагрузки - можно попробовать использовать дыру в IE (https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-ie  пункт 2), т.е. добавить оба сайта в доверенную зону и попробовать из своего окна получить доступ к DOM другого (но что-то мне подсказывает, что здесь нас ждет немало граблей)